# Approach on queue implementation for failover in azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-queues

We have azure api gateway for inbound and outbound calls for our application .

We need a queue for failed cases with exponential time logic for retry mechanism .

I need to know what will be the best solution :
whether to go with third party services like rabbit mq or kafka or Azure storage queue .

Can someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure provides Storage queues and Service Bus queues.
> Storage queues are part of the Azure Storage infrastructure and allow you to store large numbers of messages.

- Use Storage queues when the application store over 80 GB of messages in a queue.
- Service Bus queues are used when you need to receive messages without having to poll the queue, requires the queue to provide a FIFO ordered delivery, and support automatic duplicate detection, or requires transactional behaviour and atomicity when sending or receiving multiple messages.

For retry mechanism, use the `exponential backoff algorithm`.

```
int retry_Count = 0;
int maxRetry_Count = 5;
TimeSpan time_delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        break; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (retry_Count >= maxRetry_Count)
        {
            throw;
        }

        retry_Count++;
        await Task.Delay(time_delay);
        time_delay = time_delay + time_delay;
    }
}
```

And Third-party services like `RabbitMQ` or `Kafka` also be used for implementing a queue.

[RabbitMQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq) is an open-source message broker that provides robust queuing functionality.
It offers features such as message durability, routing, and flexible routing topologies.

Connecting RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information, check the [Policies in Azure API Management](https://www.svenmalvik.com/azure-apim-policies/) and [Azure Storage queues and Service Bus queues.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted)